# Datepicker range issue

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Can anyone help me out about the following issue ?

Calendar year dropdown should contain only current year and next year (current year+1). It will change accordingly every year.

I tried the following code, but it is not working:

```
        $(function() {
        $( "#date" ).datepicker({
            minDate: new Date(),

         // maxYear: "Date().getFullYear()+1",

          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends , 
         // yearRange: "Date().getFullYear()"  :  "(Date().getFullYear() + 1)"
```

Kindly help me with this.

Comment: Why is it not working?

Comment: I have been trying to find out... You  can edit this code in any Jquery editor. When I execute, It is not even showing calendar

Comment: Rather, HOW is it not working? What's the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the below code, the minimum selectable date is the `1st January of current Year` and the maximum selectable date is the `31th December of next Year`. [[demo]](http://codepen.io/pespantelis/pen/yYXywd)

```
$(function() {
  var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({

    //minDate: new Date(currentYear, 0, 1),
    minDate: new Date(),

    maxDate: new Date(currentYear+1, 11, 31),
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
  });
});
```